# More zoom in base layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, .net

I have some GIS project to do, in this project I need to place something like 20,000 trees on a map.  So I did a web app with .net that includes map that based on OpenLayers with Bing base map.

My problem is that I need to get more closer to the base map, because the maximum scale that I can get is 50 ft, but I need to be much closer to place the tree in the right place.

Is there any way to make option to do more zoom? More then 50 ft?

I tried to change the zoom levels or the resolution, but nothing worked for me until now.  Maybe I need to use other base map then Bing?  Or maybe I cannot get closer on raster map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your own basemap layer (using osm data) and use an aerial WMS as an overlay you can define additional zoom levels by adding more scales and maxZoomLevels, see example below:

```
var options = { scales: [34879630, 17439815, 8719907, 4359953, 2179976, 1089988, 544994, 272497, 136249, 68124, 34062, 17031, 8516, 4258, 2129, 1064, 500, 250, 125, 75],
                    maxExtent: bounds,
                    numZoomLevels: 20,
                    projection: "EPSG:4326",
                    units: "degrees"
                  };
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap at its highest level (level 19) gives resolution of 0.298 m/pixel (0.97769 ft/pixel). Details here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels.

If even this is not enough you can use [Client Side Zoom](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html)

Answer (score 1):

Bing/Google/OSM data is served at pre-defined scales. If the closest you can get is 50ft, that is because that's the the closet level that bing can offer you. You **can't go any lower**

OpenLayers 2.12 supports the [client zoom feature](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html), but that only works with Grid-based layers like OpenStreetMap.  It is most likely a TOS-violation if you tried to do the same thing with commercial layers like Bing/Google layers.